# Using Manim, can I draw a new object in the background of existing ones?

Tags: manim

I have illustrated the parallelogram spanned by two vectors, and would like to shade in the area of that parallelogram, which I tried to do like so:

```
from manim import *
import numpy as np

class DrawParallelogram( Scene ):
    def construct( self ):
        o = np.array( [ 0, -2, 0 ] )
        p1 = np.array( [ 3, 1, 0 ] ) # u
        p2 = np.array( [ 1, 3, 0 ] ) # v
        op1 = o + p1
        op2 = o + p2
        op3 = o + p1 + p2

        v1 = Arrow( start = o, end = op1, buff = 0, color = RED ) # u
        v2 = Arrow( start = o, end = op2, buff = 0, color = YELLOW ) # v
        v1p = Arrow( start = op2, end = op3, buff = 0, color = RED ) # u'
        v2p = Arrow( start = op1, end = op3, buff = 0, color = YELLOW ) # v'

        parallelogram = [ o, op1, op3, op2 ]
        poly = Polygon( *parallelogram, color = PURPLE, fill_opacity = 0.5 )

        self.play( AnimationGroup( Write( v1 ), Write( v2 ), Write( v1p ), Write( v2p ) ) )
        self.wait( )
        self.play( Write( poly ) )
```

However, this parallelogram colors over the arrows that I have already drawn, like so:
[image: yuck]

and I'd like it to be in the background. Is there a way to introduce a new object into the scene so that it is logically behind any of the existing ones, as if I had drawn it first, so that it would look like:

[image: desired]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [set_z_index](https://docs.manim.community/en/v0.3.0/reference/manim.mobject.mobject.Mobject.html#manim.mobject.mobject.Mobject.set_z_index) method to set the `z_index` property of the parallelogram to a value less than that of the arrows.

Here I have set it to a lower value than that of `v1`:

```
poly.set_z_index(v1.z_index - 1)
```

Alternatively you can manipulate the `z_index` property directly:

```
poly.z_index = v1.z_index - 1
```

Using the `set_z_index` method would be the cleaner solution.

Complete code:

```
from manim import *
import numpy as np

class DrawParallelogram( Scene ):
    def construct( self ):
        o = np.array( [ 0, -2, 0 ] )
        p1 = np.array( [ 3, 1, 0 ] ) # u
        p2 = np.array( [ 1, 3, 0 ] ) # v
        op1 = o + p1
        op2 = o + p2
        op3 = o + p1 + p2

        v1 = Arrow( start = o, end = op1, buff = 0, color = RED ) # u
        v2 = Arrow( start = o, end = op2, buff = 0, color = YELLOW ) # v
        v1p = Arrow( start = op2, end = op3, buff = 0, color = RED ) # u'
        v2p = Arrow( start = op1, end = op3, buff = 0, color = YELLOW ) # v'

        parallelogram = [ o, op1, op3, op2 ]
        poly = Polygon( *parallelogram, color = PURPLE, fill_opacity = 0.5 )
        # Set the z-index
        poly.set_z_index(v1.z_index - 1)

        self.play( AnimationGroup( Write( v1 ), Write( v2 ), Write( v1p ), Write( v2p ) ) )
        self.wait( )
        self.play( Write( poly ) )
```